# Beginner C arrays and incrementation

Tags: c, arrays, increment

Excuse the amateurism but I'm really struggling to understand the basic incrementing mechanisms. Are the comments correct?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
int i,j,m;
i = ++a[1]; // the value of a[1] is 3. i=3
j = ++a[1]; /* because of the previous line a[1]=3 
and now a[1]=4? but not in the line defining i? */
m = a[i++];  /* i retained the value of 3 even though the value of a[1] has changed
so finally i++ which is incremented in printf()? */
printf("%d, %d, %d", i,j,m);    
}
```

I could be answering my own question but I have fooled myself quite a few times learning C so far.

Comment: It's not really clear what the question is here - what behaviour did you observe?

Comment: the program prints 4,4,4

I'm trying to understand whether the increment changes the actual value of a[1] or is it just for the purpose of defining i, j and m.

Also I'm unsure about the post-increment being realized in the printf()

Comment: I think the question is "are the comments correct"

Comment: Yes, the `++` is changing it's operand.

Comment: pre and post inc/dec operators perform on whatever lvalue they're ascribed. In the first case, that lvalue is `a[1]`. In the second case, also `a[1]`. In the third case, simply `i`. That's it.

Comment: The first `++a[1]` changes `a[1]` from `2` to `3`, and the second `++a[1]` changes `a[1]` from `3` to `4`

Comment: @M.M that's what I needed to hear. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3):

`i = ++a[1]` will increment the value of `a[1]` to `3` and the result of `++a[1]` which is `3` will be assigned to `i`.

`j = ++a[1];` will increment the value of `a[1]` to `4` and the result of `++a[1]` which is `4` will be assigned to `j`.

`m = a[i++];`, will assign the value of `a[3]` (as `i` is 3 b now) to `m` which is `4` and `i` will be incremented by `1`. Now `i` becomes `4`.

Answer (score 3):

The thing to remember with the `++` and `--` operators is that the expression has a *result* and a *side effect*.  The *result* of `++i` is the original value of `i` plus `1`.  The *side effect* of `++i` is to add `1` to the value stored in `i`.

So, if `i` is originally `0`, then in the expression

```
j = ++i
```

`j` gets the result of `0 + 1` (the original value of `i` plus `1`).  As a side effect, `1` is added to the value currently stored in `i`.  So after this expression is evaluated, both `i` and `j` contain `1`.

The postfix version of `++` is slightly different; the *result* of `i++` is the original value of `i`, but the side effect is the same - `1` is added to the value stored in `i`.  So, if `i` is originally `0`, then

```
j = i++;
```

`j` gets the original value of `i` (`0`), and `1` is added to the value stored in `i`.  After this expression, `j` is `0` and `i` is `1`.

**Important** - the exact order in which the assignment to `j` and the side effect to `i` are executed is not specified.  `i` does *not* have to be updated before `j` is assigned, and vice versa.  Because of this, certain combinations of `++` and `--` (including but not limited to `i = i++`, `i++ * i++`, `a[i++] = i`, and `a[i] = i++`) will result in *undefined behavior*; the result will vary, *unpredictably*, depending on platform, optimization, and surrounding code.

So, let's imagine your objects are laid out in memory like so:

```
   +---+
a: | 1 | a[0]
   +---+
   | 2 | a[1]
   +---+
   | 3 | a[2]
   +---+
   | 4 | a[3]
   +---+
   | 5 | a[4]
   +---+
i: | ? |
   +---+
j: | ? |
   +---+
m: | ? |
   +---+
```

First we evaluate

```
i = ++a[1];
```

The *result* of `++a[1]` is the original value of `a[1]` plus 1 - in this case, `3`.  The *side effect* is to update the value in `a[1]`.  After this statement, your objects now look like this:

```
   +---+
a: | 1 | a[0]
   +---+
   | 3 | a[1]
   +---+
   | 3 | a[2]
   +---+
   | 4 | a[3]
   +---+
   | 5 | a[4]
   +---+
i: | 3 |
   +---+
j: | ? |
   +---+
m: | ? |
   +---+
```

Now we execute

```
j = ++a[1];
```

Same deal - `j` gets the value of `a[1]` plus 1, and the side effect is to update `a[1]`.  After evaluation, we have

```
   +---+
a: | 1 | a[0]
   +---+
   | 4 | a[1]
   +---+
   | 3 | a[2]
   +---+
   | 4 | a[3]
   +---+
   | 5 | a[4]
   +---+
i: | 3 |
   +---+
j: | 4 |
   +---+
m: | ? |
   +---+
```

Finally, we have

```
m = a[i++];
```

The result of `i++` is `3`, so `m` gets the value stored in `a[3]`.  The side effect is to add `1` to the value stored in `i`.  Now, our objects look like

```
   +---+
a: | 1 | a[0]
   +---+
   | 4 | a[1]
   +---+
   | 3 | a[2]
   +---+
   | 4 | a[3]
   +---+
   | 5 | a[4]
   +---+
i: | 4 |
   +---+
j: | 4 |
   +---+
m: | 4 |
   +---+
```